# Check for existence of method with class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a type-trait to perform a compile-time check for the existence of a method with a class type. Below is what I implemented. I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

T = The type to check for method.

R = Method's return type.

P = Method's param type.

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename P>
struct HasBarImpl {
    template<typename> static std::false_type Test(...);

    template<typename U>
    static auto Test(P* p) ->
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(declval(U).Bar(p)), R>, std::true_type>;

    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(Test<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value;
};

template<typename T, typename R, typename P>
constexpr bool HasBar = HasBarImpl<T, R, P>::value;


struct Foo {
    void Bar(int*) {}
};


TEST_CASE("Check for method's existence") {
    bool r = false;
    if constexpr (HasBar<Foo, void, int>) {
        r = true;
    }

    CHECK(r == true); // Fails
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting the order of the arguments wrong in you test?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: True; fixed the posting. Though, that was not the issue. The posting was a copy paste error. The problem persists.

Comment: I believe it's for the abuse of `std::declval`, you should use it like `std::declval<U>()`, rather than `std::declval(U)`.

Comment: @SHP: Yep, that was it!